# Migrate data from oracle to mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g, migration, database-migration

We are doing data migration from oracle to mysql using etl tool where source and target are in different hosts.

During fail over of the source we are set to do data migration with dump export/import.

Is there any way to import oracle dump directly into MYSQL without third party tools?

If its possible please explain a feasible soultion

Answer (score 0):

Oracle import/export is designed to move databases/data between Oracle databases ideally of the same version, so no - this isn't an appropriate solution. Depending on the size and complexity of your database you could do it with scripts - sqldeveloper/modeller (free oracle tools) should help with this if you don't know how to do it yourself. I think sqlmodeller may allow you to generate a schema for another database (you can do it for sqlserver). The main thing to overcome is syntax differences between oracle and mysql as well as differences in datatypes - if you have been consistent in your oracle db design it should be fairly easy to overcome these with find/replace

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnru